# How to create an isolate using the compute function for Recursive function

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using the **recursive function** for a huge data which causes the app to freeze for a few seconds, so I want to create **an isolate using the compute function** for that recursive function

So I make a simple example with the same data structure as my live project, please help me to include the isolate fuction as I noted in the code below.

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class Item {
  Item({this.id, this.childIds, this.parentIds});

  final String id;
  final List<String> childIds;
  List<String> parentIds;

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'Item{id: $id, childIds: $childIds, parentIds: $parentIds}';
  }
}

List<Item> data = [
  Item(id: 'aaa', childIds: ['ccc']),
  Item(id: 'bbb', childIds: ['ccc', 'ddd']),
  Item(id: 'ccc', childIds: ['ggg']),
  Item(id: 'ddd', childIds: ['fff', 'hhh']),
  Item(id: 'eee', childIds: ['hhh']),
  Item(id: 'fff', childIds: ['ggg']),
  Item(id: 'ggg', childIds: null),
  Item(id: 'hhh', childIds: null),
];

void main() async {
  await data.map((e) async {
    e.parentIds = await idFindParent(e.id);
    // Option 1: create Isolate here
    // e.parentIds = await compute(idFindParent,e.id);
  }).toList();
  data.forEach((e) => print(e));
}

List<String> idFindParent(String id) {
  List<Item> itemsHasChild = data.where((e) => e.childIds != null).toList();
  List<Item> parents = itemsHasChild.where((parent) => parent.childIds.contains(id)).toList();
  if (parents.isEmpty) return [];
  List<String> parentIds = parents.map((e) => e.id).toSet().toList();
  return findParentRecursive(parentIds);
  // Option 2: create Isolate here
  // return compute(findParentRecursive, parentIds);
}

List<String> findParentRecursive(List<String> ids) {
  bool everyParentIsEmpty = ids.every((id) => data
      .where((e) => e.childIds != null)
      .toList()
      .where((e) => e.childIds.any((childIds) => childIds.contains(id)))
      .toList()
      .isEmpty);

  if (everyParentIsEmpty) return ids;

  List<String> _ids = [];
  ids.map((id) {
    List<Item> itemsHasChild = data.where((e) => e.childIds != null).toList();
    List<Item> parents =
        itemsHasChild.where((e) => e.childIds.any((childIds) => childIds.contains(id))).toList();
    if (parents.isEmpty) {
      _ids.add(id);
    } else if (parents.isNotEmpty) {
      parents.map((e) {
        return _ids.add(e.id);
      }).toList();
    }
  }).toList();

  return findParentRecursive(_ids.toSet().toList());
}
```

Comment: Maybe the reason it is freezing is because the code is poorly optimized? You have pointless calls to `map(...).toList()` where you don't actually care about the return value. Those should be for loops instead. You have unnecessary calls to `.toList()` all over the place. You would be better off with `childIds` and `parentIds` being `Set<String>` instead of `List<String>` so that you can check membership in `O(1)` time instead of `O(N)` time...

Comment: @mmcdon20 ye, I haven't thought of it, could you pls help me optimize it with the answer of full code? I'm really new to code and I don't know much about Set<String> xD

Comment: sure, I just posted a breakdown in an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note**: idFindParent do not use "**UI**" code. Ex: **import** some ui **dependencies** and use it in **idFindParent** function.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:isolate';

class Item {
  Item({this.id, this.childIds, this.parentIds});

  final String id;
  final List<String> childIds;
  List<String> parentIds;

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'Item{id: $id, childIds: $childIds, parentIds: $parentIds}';
  }
}

List<Item> data = [
  Item(id: 'aaa', childIds: ['ccc']),
  Item(id: 'bbb', childIds: ['ccc', 'ddd']),
  Item(id: 'ccc', childIds: ['ggg']),
  Item(id: 'ddd', childIds: ['fff', 'hhh']),
  Item(id: 'eee', childIds: ['hhh']),
  Item(id: 'fff', childIds: ['ggg']),
  Item(id: 'ggg', childIds: null),
  Item(id: 'hhh', childIds: null),
];

void main() async {
  var dataMap = await data.map((e) async {
    Completer<List<String>> completer = Completer();
    isolateData(e.id, completer);
    e.parentIds = await completer.future;
    return e;
  }).toList();
  var results = await Future.wait(dataMap);
  print(results);
}

void isolateData(String id, Completer<List<String>> completer) async {
  var port = ReceivePort();
  var isolate = await Isolate.spawn(
    idFindParent,
    [id, port.sendPort],
  );
  port.listen((result) {
    completer.complete(result);
    isolate.kill();
    port.close();
  });
}

void idFindParent(List<Object> args) {
  String id = args[0] as String;
  SendPort port = args[1] as SendPort;

  List<Item> itemsHasChild = data.where((e) => e.childIds != null).toList();
  List<Item> parents = itemsHasChild.where((parent) => parent.childIds.contains(id)).toList();
  if (parents.isEmpty) {
    List<String> ids = [];
    port.send(ids);
    return;
  } else {
    List<String> parentIds = parents.map((e) => e.id).toSet().toList();
    var ids = findParentRecursive(parentIds);
    port.send(ids);
    return;
  }
}

List<String> findParentRecursive(List<String> ids) {
  bool everyParentIsEmpty =
      ids.every((id) => data.where((e) => e.childIds != null).toList().where((e) => e.childIds.any((childIds) => childIds.contains(id))).toList().isEmpty);
  if (everyParentIsEmpty) return ids;
  List<String> _ids = [];
  ids.map((id) {
    List<Item> itemsHasChild = data.where((e) => e.childIds != null).toList();
    List<Item> parents = itemsHasChild.where((e) => e.childIds.any((childIds) => childIds.contains(id))).toList();
    if (parents.isEmpty) {
      _ids.add(id);
    } else if (parents.isNotEmpty) {
      parents.map((e) {
        return _ids.add(e.id);
      }).toList();
    }
  }).toList();

  return findParentRecursive(_ids.toSet().toList());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in our discussion above, there are a number of things you can do to optimize your code to improve the performance.

One thing you can do is use a `Set<String>` instead of a `List<String>` for `childIds` and `parentIds` properties of the `Item` class. The way you are using these properties is to store a collection of ids, and then later check if a particular id is a member of this collection using the `contains` method. Both `List` and `Set` have a `contains` method, but the performance characteristics are different for each.

For a `List`, the way that `myList.contains(x)` works is that it will check if the first element is equivalent to `x`, and if not then it will check if the second element is equivalent to `x` and so on until it either finds an equivalent match and returns true or it reaches the end of the list after exhaustively checking every element and returns false. Therefore the complexity of `contains` as implemented by `List` is `O(N)` where `N` is the length of the list. Meaning that `contains` does up to `N` operations.

Comparatively, the way that a `Set` implements `contains` is quite different. Unlike a `List` a `Set` is a collection of items that will not contain duplicate items, and is not necessarily ordered. The default implementation for a `Set` in dart is [LinkedHashSet](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.16.2/dart-collection/LinkedHashSet-class.html), which stores elements according to a hashing algorithm. So when `mySet.contains(x)` is called it will look at the `hashCode` for `x` and jump directly to the corresponding location in the hashtable that is associated with that `hashCode`. Thus the complexity of `contains` for `Set` is `O(1)`. Meaning that `contains` does only `1` operation. *(NOTE: technically this is an oversimplification, contains here is technically considered to be amortized O(1), since sometimes two  different values will have the same hashCode, but it happens infrequently enough that most of the time it will only take 1 operation, and we generally treat amortized O(1) operations as if they were O(1))*

Thus I ended up reworking the `Item` class as follows:

```dart
class Item {
  const Item({
    required this.id,
    this.childIds = const {},
    this.parentIds = const {},
  });

  final String id;
  final Set<String> childIds;
  final Set<String> parentIds;

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'Item{id: $id, childIds: $childIds, parentIds: $parentIds}';
  }
}
```

Based on the syntax of your original code, I think you are using a much earlier version of `dart` than I am. The `required` keyword was introduced in dart 2.12. If you are using an earlier version I think you can simply remove the `required` keyword. I also opted to use empty sets instead of null values.

---

Let's look at the `idFindParent` function next.

For context, this is the orginal implementation:

```dart
List<String> idFindParent(String id) {
  List<Item> itemsHasChild = data.where((e) => e.childIds != null).toList();
  List<Item> parents = itemsHasChild.where((parent) => parent.childIds.contains(id)).toList();
  if (parents.isEmpty) return [];
  List<String> parentIds = parents.map((e) => e.id).toSet().toList();
  return findParentRecursive(parentIds);
}
```

We can start by updating the return type to a `Set<String>` since we changed `parentIds` to be a `Set<String>` as well.

```dart
Set<String> idFindParent(String id) { ... }
```

Next, lets examine this line of code from your original solution:

```dart
List<Item> itemsHasChild = data.where((e) => e.childIds != null).toList();
```

Since I am representing no ids as an empty set rather than null, we can adjust it to the following:

```dart
List<Item> itemsHasChild = data.where((e) => e.childIds.isNotEmpty).toList();
```

But there is a more significant improvement we can make here. Converting the result to a List is unnecessary work, we can simply eliminate this operation altogether:

```dart
Iterable<Item> itemsHasChild = data.where((e) => e.childIds.isNotEmpty);
```

Now lets look at the next line from your original solution:

```dart
List<Item> parents = itemsHasChild.where((parent) => parent.childIds.contains(id)).toList();
```

Again, we can eliminate the call to `toList`:

```dart
Iterable<Item> parents = itemsHasChild.where((parent) => parent.childIds.contains(id));
```

The next line is:

```dart
if (parents.isEmpty) return [];
```

Here we just want to return a `Set` instead of a `List`:

```dart
if (parents.isEmpty) return {};
```

Next up is:

```dart
List<String> parentIds = parents.map((e) => e.id).toSet().toList();
```

We ultimately want a `Set` so we can do:

```dart
Set<String> parentIds = parents.map((e) => e.id).toSet();
```

But I using a `Set` Literal here would be slightly better since there is no intermediate step:

```dart
Set<String> parentIds = {for (final e in parents) e.id};
```

Putting everything together we have:

```dart
Set<String> idFindParent(String id) {
  Iterable<Item> itemsHasChild = data.where((e) => e.childIds.isNotEmpty);
  Iterable<Item> parents =
      itemsHasChild.where((parent) => parent.childIds.contains(id));
  if (parents.isEmpty) return {};
  Set<String> parentIds = {for (final e in parents) e.id};
  return findParentRecursive(parentIds);
}
```

But there is one more change I think we can make. `itemsHasChild` isn't really doing anything useful for us here, I think we can safely eliminate it:

```dart
Set<String> idFindParent(String id) {
  Iterable<Item> parents = data.where((parent) => parent.childIds.contains(id));
  if (parents.isEmpty) return {};
  Set<String> parentIds = {for (final e in parents) e.id};
  return findParentRecursive(parentIds);
}
```

---

---

Now let's look at the `findParentRecursive` function.

For context the original implementation is as follows:

```dart
List<String> findParentRecursive(List<String> ids) {
  bool everyParentIsEmpty = ids.every((id) => data
      .where((e) => e.childIds != null)
      .toList()
      .where((e) => e.childIds.any((childIds) => childIds.contains(id)))
      .toList()
      .isEmpty);

  if (everyParentIsEmpty) return ids;

  List<String> _ids = [];
  ids.map((id) {
    List<Item> itemsHasChild = data.where((e) => e.childIds != null).toList();
    List<Item> parents =
        itemsHasChild.where((e) => e.childIds.any((childIds) => childIds.contains(id))).toList();
    if (parents.isEmpty) {
      _ids.add(id);
    } else if (parents.isNotEmpty) {
      parents.map((e) {
        return _ids.add(e.id);
      }).toList();
    }
  }).toList();

  return findParentRecursive(_ids.toSet().toList());
}
```

Again we want to update the return type to a `Set<String>`, and also the parameter type:

```dart
Set<String> findParentRecursive(Set<String> ids) { ... }
```

Next the first line is:

```dart
bool everyParentIsEmpty = ids.every((id) => data
    .where((e) => e.childIds != null)
    .toList()
    .where((e) => e.childIds.any((childIds) => childIds.contains(id)))
    .toList()
    .isEmpty);
```

Here both calls to `toList` and also the first call to `where` is unnecessary:

```dart
bool everyParentIsEmpty = ids.every((id) => data
    .where((e) => e.childIds.any((childIds) => childIds.contains(id)))
    .isEmpty);
```

Furthermore, the call to `any` within the `where` clause doesn't seem necessary:

```dart
bool everyParentIsEmpty = ids.every((id) => data
    .where((e) => e.childIds.contains(id)).isEmpty);
```

The next couple lines are:

```dart
if (everyParentIsEmpty) return ids;

List<String> _ids = [];
```

Again, we just want to return a `Set`.

```dart
if (everyParentIsEmpty) return ids;

List<String> _ids = {};
```

Next we have a `.map(...).toList()` operation, ignore the inside for now:

```dart
ids.map((id) {
  ...
}).toList();
```

Why? Just why? Please do not do this. Only use a `map` if you require the return value. There is a reason for loops exist.

```dart
for (final id in ids) {
  ...
}
```

Now that thats sorted, lets look at the inside. first we have:

```dart
List<Item> itemsHasChild = data.where((e) => e.childIds != null).toList();
List<Item> parents =
    itemsHasChild.where((e) => e.childIds.any((childIds) => childIds.contains(id))).toList();
```

If you recall the same operation was done in the `idFindParent` function, so we can simplify this the same way:

```dart
Iterable<Item> parents = data.where((e) => e.childIds.contains(id));
```

Next let's look at the if condition:

```dart
if (parents.isEmpty) {
  _ids.add(id);
} else if (parents.isNotEmpty) {
  parents.map((e) {
    return _ids.add(e.id);
  }).toList();
}
```

Again, we have a `.map(...).toList()` function that should be a for loop. Also the else if can be simplified to just an else:

```dart
if (parents.isEmpty) {
  _ids.add(id);
} else {
  for (final e in parents) {
    _ids.add(e.id);
  }
}
```

And then the return statement:

```dart
return findParentRecursive(_ids.toSet().toList());
```

Can be simplified to just:

```dart
return findParentRecursive(_ids);
```

Putting it together, we get:

```dart
Set<String> findParentRecursive(Set<String> ids) {
  bool everyParentIsEmpty =
      ids.every((id) => data.where((e) => e.childIds.contains(id)).isEmpty);

  if (everyParentIsEmpty) return ids;

  Set<String> _ids = {};
  for (final id in ids) {
    Iterable<Item> parents = data.where((e) => e.childIds.contains(id));
    if (parents.isEmpty) {
      _ids.add(id);
    } else {
      for (final e in parents) {
        _ids.add(e.id);
      }
    }
  }

  return findParentRecursive(_ids);
}
```

---

---

Before we go on, are there any further optimizations that can be made? I think we can do better still. If we reevaluate the algorithm at a high level, I really don't see the need for a recursive function at all, in fact we can simplify `idFindParent` and eliminate `findParentRecursive` altogether.

All we really need to do is loop through the original data and return a `Set` of ids where the given id is one of the `childIds`.

```dart
Set<String> idFindParent(String id) {
  return {
    for (final e in data)
      if (e.childIds.contains(id)) e.id,
  };
}
```

---

---

Let's have a look at `main` now:

```dart
void main() async {
  await data.map((e) async {
    e.parentIds = await idFindParent(e.id);
  }).toList();
  data.forEach((e) => print(e));
}
```

Again, we have a `.map(...).toList()` that should be a for loop. Also `idFindParent` doesn't return a `Future` so there is no point `await`ing it.

Also note that since I updated `parentIds` to be `final` in the `Item` class I have to approach this by creating new `Item`s, instead of updating the old ones, this how I updated it:

```dart
void main() {
  data = [
    for (final e in data)
      Item(id: e.id, childIds: e.childIds, parentIds: idFindParent(e.id)),
  ];

  data.forEach(print);
}
```

The full program is as follows:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class Item {
  const Item({
    required this.id,
    this.childIds = const {},
    this.parentIds = const {},
  });

  final String id;
  final Set<String> childIds;
  final Set<String> parentIds;

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'Item{id: $id, childIds: $childIds, parentIds: $parentIds}';
  }
}

List<Item> data = [
  Item(id: 'aaa', childIds: {'ccc'}),
  Item(id: 'bbb', childIds: {'ccc', 'ddd'}),
  Item(id: 'ccc', childIds: {'ggg'}),
  Item(id: 'ddd', childIds: {'fff', 'hhh'}),
  Item(id: 'eee', childIds: {'hhh'}),
  Item(id: 'fff', childIds: {'ggg'}),
  Item(id: 'ggg', childIds: {}),
  Item(id: 'hhh', childIds: {}),
];

void main() {
  data = [
    for (final e in data)
      Item(id: e.id, childIds: e.childIds, parentIds: idFindParent(e.id)),
  ];

  data.forEach(print);
}

Set<String> idFindParent(String id) {
  return {
    for (final e in data)
      if (e.childIds.contains(id)) e.id,
  };
}
```

So now that we have a full solution we can analyze the complexity of the whole program.

In main, we loop over each element in `data`, which is `N` operations (again where `N` is the length of `data`). However at each iteration, we are calling the `idFindParent` function which also loops over each element in data giving another `N` operations. We have also established that `contains` here is `1` operation as defined by the `Set`. Therefore the total complexity is `N * N * 1` or `O(N^2)` (N squared).

---

---

So what if after all of that, we still want to use flutter's compute function?

We would need to create a function that does the work we want to pass to compute:

```dart
List<Item> computeData(List<Item> data) {
  return [
    for (final e in data)
      Item(id: e.id, childIds: e.childIds, parentIds: idFindParent(e.id)),
  ];
}
```

And then we can just update `main` as follows:

```dart
void main() async {
  data = await compute(computeData, data);
  data.forEach(print);
}
```

---

---

EDIT: I was thinking about the problem, and it occurred to me that there is another potential optimization to consider.

I have implemented it below. This solution only needs to change `main` from the solution above, and no longer requires the `idFindParent` function.

```dart
void main() async {
  Map<String, Set<String>> parentIds = {};
  for (final e in data) {
    for (final c in e.childIds) {
      parentIds[c] ??= {};
      parentIds[c]?.add(e.id);
    }
  }

  data = [
    for (final e in data)
      Item(id: e.id, childIds: e.childIds, parentIds: parentIds[e.id] ?? {}),
  ];

  data.forEach(print);
}
```

What this solution does differently is it loops through all of the elements of `data` and for each element loops through its `childIds` and adds them to a `Map`, building up each set of parent ids as it goes along. Then after that we loop over data again to build each item, and and simply retrieve the parentIds set that was previously built up. The complexity of this is `N` for the number of elements in `data` (the outer for loop) multiplied by `M` which is the average size of each `childIds` set (the inner for loop), plus an additional `N` operations for looping over `data` one last time. Thus the total complexity is `O(N*M+N)`.

If you recall, the previous solution had a complexity of `O(N^2)`, and this solution has a complexity of `O(N*M+N)`. Which takes fewer operations? Well it depends on the size of `M`. If `M >= N` then it will take more operations, but if `M < N` it should take less. Again `M` represents the average size of each `childIds` set. I suspect it is likely that the size of each of these sets is smaller on average than the length of `data`.

That said there is one downside to this approach. Creating the map of `parentIds` is going to use a bit more memory than the previous solution.

---

---

EDIT (AGAIN):

> thank you for taking the extra time to research it more deeply, but without using recursion, the `parentID` found is the closest, not the last. (Ex: id: "hhh" with the above code => `parentIds : {ddd, eee}`, but I want "hhh" => `parentIds: {bbb, eee}}`

Apologies, somehow I overlooked that the intent was to get the root parents, that does complicate things a bit, but I think the previous solution serves as a good starting point.

In the solution above we create `Map<String, Set<String>> parentIds` which contains the closest parents for each id. It should be more efficient to recursively search `parentIds` to find the root parents than to search `data` to find the root parents.

I have put together a solution using this approach below:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class Item {
  const Item({
    required this.id,
    this.childIds = const {},
    this.parentIds = const {},
  });

  final String id;
  final Set<String> childIds;
  final Set<String> parentIds;

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'Item{id: $id, childIds: $childIds, parentIds: $parentIds}';
  }
}

List<Item> data = [
  Item(id: 'aaa', childIds: {'ccc'}),
  Item(id: 'bbb', childIds: {'ccc', 'ddd'}),
  Item(id: 'ccc', childIds: {'ggg'}),
  Item(id: 'ddd', childIds: {'fff', 'hhh'}),
  Item(id: 'eee', childIds: {'hhh'}),
  Item(id: 'fff', childIds: {'ggg'}),
  Item(id: 'ggg', childIds: {}),
  Item(id: 'hhh', childIds: {}),
];

void main() async {
  data = computeData(data); // OR: data = await compute(computeData, data);
  data.forEach(print);
}

List<Item> computeData(List<Item> data) {
  Map<String, Set<String>> parentIds = {};
  for (final e in data) {
    for (final c in e.childIds) {
      parentIds[c] ??= {};
      parentIds[c]?.add(e.id);
    }
  }
  return [
    for (final e in data)
      Item(id: e.id, childIds: e.childIds, parentIds: rootIds(parentIds, e.id)),
  ];
}

Set<String> rootIds(Map<String, Set<String>> parentIds, String id) {
  return {
    for (final parent in parentIds[id] ?? {})
      if (parentIds[parent]?.isNotEmpty ?? false)
        ...rootIds(parentIds, parent)
      else
        parent,
  };
}
```

Comment: This is by far the most detailed and dedicated answer I've had since joining StackOverflow, it took me almost a day to learn every single sentence in it, every word is valuable, especially for someone with no codebase like me. Thank you for your enthusiasm, your information will help greatly improve the performance of my future applications. xD

Comment: @Kel, Glad I could be of help. I took another look at the problem, and I think there is an additional optimization that I overlooked as well. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: thank you for taking the extra time to research it more deeply, but without using recursion, the `parentID` found is the closest, not the last. (Ex: id: "hhh" with the above code => `parentIds : {ddd, eee}`, but I want "hhh" => `parentIds: {bbb, eee}}`  [img](https://i.imgur.com/sk6B7v7.png)

Comment: @Kel, ah right somehow I overlooked this. I have made one more edit above.

Comment: this is incredible, after half a day to try to understand your recent update and apply it to a real project with huge data, the result is amazing, it reduced freeze from `3.8s` to `1.3s`. Even better, I understood more about the usefulness of `Map<String, Set<String>>`, Thanks for saving my ass xD

Comment: @Kel, glad to help, although even with the improvements the overall complexity is I think `O(N*M+N*M*D)` where `D` is the average distance to a root parent. Still an improvement over the original implementation but not great in terms of complexity. If you want to improve performance further, I would think about things outside the scope of the question, like where does the data come from, and can keeping track of parents be handled more efficiently at the source? (ie a server/database) If the data can arrive at your app already in the correct format then there would be no need to transform it.